# No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, xps

I  have an issue where my bluetooth randomly cuts out, like so:

[image: Screenshot_Of_Settings_Menu]

[image]

I have read some existing Ask Ubuntu posts on this issue.

I followed this post: [Bluetooth randomly cutting out in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023184/bluetooth-randomly-cutting-out-in-ubuntu)

and ran `sudo apt install -y linux-oem` and restarted my computer, but I'm still having the error.

I also looked at this post ["No Bluetooth found Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875901/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth)

but the output of `rfkill list all` was:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

What other fixes are there to this problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem. It used to worked correctly and then I put "turn off" and now I can't switch it back again.

Comment: any solution to this bug ?

Answer (score 7):

First, run this command for switching on devices

```
hcitool dev
```

After that run this

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

for checking status of your, Bluetooth run this

```
systemctl status bluetooth
```

Comment: Did not completely fix the issue for me, but at least it helped me get closer as i now have a non-dead output returned from `systemctl status` for the `bluetooth.service`.

Comment: All run, status is "systemctl status bluetooth... Active: active (running)", all good.... but **not fix the problem**.

Comment: did anyone find any solution to this ??

Comment: Any solution please?

Comment: tried almost all the possible solution including reinstalling the bluetooth . no fix . any one found any solution yet ?

Comment: @sassy.geek yes for me I did. If everyting else fails. Turn off you computer and make sure the power is disconnected so that the motherboard doesn't get any power as well. Then, reconnect it to a powersocket and reboot. Then bluetooth started working for me. And only then, even after trying everything else on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try to perform a cold reboot. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

My Bluetooth disappeared in both Ubuntu and Windows after turning it off in Uubuntu. I was never able to turn it back on from either OSs. Aman Singh's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106331/103884) did exactly what @peter-krauss says in the comment to that answer.

What *did* work for me was 1) From the BIOS turn off the WiFi adapter (which controls both Bluetooth and Wifi in my system), 2) Reboot and 3) Turn it back in the BIOS again.

Again, somewhat lame answer but mine is working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying all suggestions out there, the only thing that really fixed the issue for me was to update my BIOS to the most recent version.

Essentially follow the following steps:

1. Download the BIOS from your hardware provider[Intel in my case].
   Save it onto a USB drive.
2. Reboot your machine and and press F7 during boot. This key might be different based on your hardware.
3. Select the bios file you'd downloaded and let the bios upgrade. On
   reboot your Bluetooth should be back and functional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the command line and perform a system restart.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt install bluez
```