# No Bluetooth on System76 machine, 18.04 Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, system-settings

First off, I have checked a bunch of other threads on here, and none of them have a solution. I had Bluetooth working two weeks ago, wasn't using it for a couple of days, and now it's not working at all (images from system settings attached).

[image: no bt found][image]

It shows it is working from the command line after following instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073678/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the system settings still show no bluetooth, so I can't connect to anything.

Machine: System76 Thelio

Ubuntu 18.04

Here is the output from the system76 troubleshooting page and recommended commands from other stackexchange pages:

`lsmod | grep bluetooth`

`bluetooth             552960  7 bnep
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth`

`dmesg | grep Bluetooth`

`Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
 Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
 Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
 Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
 Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
 Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
 Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
 Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized`

`systemctl status bluetooth`

`● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-06 21:30:40 PST; 1h 27min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 2282 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2282 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

`rfkill list all`

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

`00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)`
    `Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]`
    `Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi`

### `Kernel modules: iwlwifi`

`01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb`
`02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a808]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1209:1776 InterBiometrics 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

I have all the latest updates, I have restarted the computer twice. How should I fix this?

Comment: Is there an option in BIOS to enable bluetooth?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I don't know, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue come up with my Thelio and Pop!_OS 21.10 (Ubuntu derivative). After trying a few different things I ended up fixing it by doing the following:

1. Powering off the system
2. Removing the USB hub that I was using
3. Plugged USB devices directly into my system
4. Powered it back up and it was working

It's worth noting that it was working properly before with the same USB hub and devices plugged in. It just so happens that right before I booted the system and discovered this issue that the power in my office was shut off while the system was in use. Not implying the correlation is causation here but worth pointing out nonetheless. Not sure if this will be helpful or not for anyone else, but it does seem odd that the USB hub would cause an issue for Bluetooth.

Comment: If it is not an answer it is a comment. Also Pop OS is off topic on this site.