# No bluetooth found. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

My bluetooth cannot be turned on. I am having this problem often and I just do a reboot but now it is getting on my nerves. I have a bluetooth but it is still not detected and I have to restart.

I tried checking the status of bluetooth using `systemctl status bluetooth` and the result is

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-09-05 22:20:16 IST; 6min ago
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 28834 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 9239)
 Memory: 1.8M
    CPU: 41ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
         └─28834 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
Sep 05 22:20:16 rushi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 05 22:20:16 rushi bluetoothd[28834]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Sep 05 22:20:16 rushi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 05 22:20:16 rushi bluetoothd[28834]: Starting SDP server
Sep 05 22:20:16 rushi bluetoothd[28834]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21
```

I took reference from this post -> [No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073678/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts)

But didn't work for me. I ran `rfkill list all` and result was

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

And I noticed that this issue started coming when I had the usb problem. In that during starting the PC it would show error `110` and then I would plug the usb in and out then it would show error `71` and start boot up. Maybe it is connected but it happens 4 out of 10 times only so yeah.

I know this post is HUGE  so I will end here. Any solutions except those stupid restarts.

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; suro dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:06f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0074]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b695 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[sudo] password for rushi: 
[    2.716383] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.716478] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.716479] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.716484] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.716486] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.716490] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.757399] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.4 build 0 week 30 2018
[    2.758407] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    2.758410] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.758411] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.758412] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.758412] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.758413] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.765245] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    3.311644] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.311648] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.311652] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.416284] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.416385] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1612436 usecs
[    4.416434] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.431401] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14633 usecs
[    4.431712] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-4.ddc
[    4.433400] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    4.436397] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.4 build 126 week 5 2022
[   15.161518] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.161524] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.161527] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 7319.077619] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[ 7324.113249]  btintel snd_seq_device videobuf2_common snd_timer cec iwlwifi bluetooth aesni_intel crypto_simd rc_core videodev snd cryptd i2c_algo_bit input_leds rapl msi_wmi fb_sys_fops ecdh_generic syscopyarea nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate mc serio_raw wmi_bmof mxm_wmi cfg80211 ee1004 sparse_keymap soundcore ecc sysfillrect hid_multitouch mei_me sysimgblt mei intel_pch_thermal mac_hid soc_button_array acpi_pad sch_fq_codel coretemp ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ramoops pstore_blk mtd reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse r8169 i2c_i801 nvme i2c_smbus realtek nvme_core intel_lpss_pci ahci i2c_hid_acpi intel_lpss i2c_hid xhci_pci libahci idma64 xhci_pci_renesas hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[ 7336.063470] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000017bf64ec submission failed (90)
[ 7336.063477] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[ 7336.063479] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000017bf64ec submission failed (90)
[ 7336.063480] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[ 7371.150306] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[ 7399.449644] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000032e82755 submission failed (90)
[ 7399.449651] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[ 7399.449653] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000032e82755 submission failed (90)
[ 7399.449654] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[ 7449.946767] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000009b6cfbd4 submission failed (90)
[ 7449.946773] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[ 7449.946794] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000009b6cfbd4 submission failed (90)
[ 7449.946795] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12008.407530] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000005e2b5a70 submission failed (90)
[12008.407535] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12008.407537] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000005e2b5a70 submission failed (90)
[12008.407538] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12342.442961] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[12351.412611] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000aea4bf3e submission failed (90)
[12351.412617] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12351.412619] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000aea4bf3e submission failed (90)
[12351.412620] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12387.014631] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000001d3f48a8 submission failed (90)
[12387.014635] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12387.014637] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000001d3f48a8 submission failed (90)
[12387.014638] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12400.811796] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[12403.483700]  btintel snd_seq_device videobuf2_common snd_timer cec iwlwifi bluetooth aesni_intel crypto_simd rc_core videodev snd cryptd i2c_algo_bit input_leds rapl msi_wmi fb_sys_fops ecdh_generic syscopyarea nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate mc serio_raw wmi_bmof mxm_wmi cfg80211 ee1004 sparse_keymap soundcore ecc sysfillrect hid_multitouch mei_me sysimgblt mei intel_pch_thermal mac_hid soc_button_array acpi_pad sch_fq_codel coretemp ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ramoops pstore_blk mtd reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse r8169 i2c_i801 nvme i2c_smbus realtek nvme_core intel_lpss_pci ahci i2c_hid_acpi intel_lpss i2c_hid xhci_pci libahci idma64 xhci_pci_renesas hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[12437.511629] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000f4bd049c submission failed (90)
[12437.511635] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12437.511657] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000f4bd049c submission failed (90)
[12437.511658] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12443.136406] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[12445.343160]  btintel snd_seq_device videobuf2_common snd_timer cec iwlwifi bluetooth aesni_intel crypto_simd rc_core videodev snd cryptd i2c_algo_bit input_leds rapl msi_wmi fb_sys_fops ecdh_generic syscopyarea nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate mc serio_raw wmi_bmof mxm_wmi cfg80211 ee1004 sparse_keymap soundcore ecc sysfillrect hid_multitouch mei_me sysimgblt mei intel_pch_thermal mac_hid soc_button_array acpi_pad sch_fq_codel coretemp ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ramoops pstore_blk mtd reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse r8169 i2c_i801 nvme i2c_smbus realtek nvme_core intel_lpss_pci ahci i2c_hid_acpi intel_lpss i2c_hid xhci_pci libahci idma64 xhci_pci_renesas hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[12452.051507] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000052afd3f2 submission failed (90)
[12452.051529] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12452.051531] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000052afd3f2 submission failed (90)
[12452.051532] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12457.672543] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[12514.013699] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000016fa53fa submission failed (90)
[12514.013721] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[12514.013723] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000016fa53fa submission failed (90)
[12514.013724] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[13219.133785] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[13508.540999] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000006db61252 submission failed (90)
[13508.541028] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[13508.541030] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000006db61252 submission failed (90)
[13508.541031] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[14079.547642] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[14094.951037] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000df486852 submission failed (90)
[14094.951042] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[14094.951044] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000df486852 submission failed (90)
[14094.951045] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16712.747835] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[16938.116133] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000056182a9a submission failed (90)
[16938.116138] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16938.116140] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000056182a9a submission failed (90)
[16938.116141] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16950.366155] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000052ab2277 submission failed (90)
[16950.366161] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16950.366163] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000052ab2277 submission failed (90)
[16950.366164] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16956.447165] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000c2205f7e submission failed (90)
[16956.447171] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16956.447173] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000c2205f7e submission failed (90)
[16956.447174] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[16962.015841] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[17613.652601] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000002679e504 submission failed (90)
[17613.652608] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[17613.652610] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000002679e504 submission failed (90)
[17613.652611] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[17632.374341] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000073a277d3 submission failed (90)
[17632.374347] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[17632.374349] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000073a277d3 submission failed (90)
[17632.374350] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18023.543537] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000094c8f8ad submission failed (90)
[18023.543545] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18023.543547] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000094c8f8ad submission failed (90)
[18023.543548] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18253.560107] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[18258.966721] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004e05c932 submission failed (90)
[18258.966736] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18258.966740] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004e05c932 submission failed (90)
[18258.966742] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18305.360669] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[18533.677658] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000007e937300 submission failed (90)
[18533.677664] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18533.677666] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000007e937300 submission failed (90)
[18533.677668] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18538.829006] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[18553.655655] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000065cf8aad submission failed (90)
[18553.655660] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[18553.655663] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000065cf8aad submission failed (90)
[18553.655664] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[30856.212530] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[30856.804500] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004667f1e9 submission failed (90)
[30856.804507] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[30856.804509] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004667f1e9 submission failed (90)
[30856.804511] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[31216.568633] Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[31223.973884] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000ceffe969 submission failed (90)
[31223.973892] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[31223.973895] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000ceffe969 submission failed (90)
[31223.973896] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[31649.772732] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000921fb454 submission failed (90)
[31649.772737] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[31649.772739] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000921fb454 submission failed (90)
[31649.772740] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-90)
[33863.299393] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[33865.315318] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33867.331532] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[33869.347435] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33871.395559] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[33871.395564] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33873.411488] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33873.411492] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33875.431548] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33875.431553] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33877.447646] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33877.447650] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33879.459555] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33879.459561] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33881.475760] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33881.475766] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33883.527623] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33883.527627] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33885.539627] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33885.539631] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33887.559647] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33887.559651] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33889.571673] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33889.571687] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33891.587888] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33891.587904] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33893.603708] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33893.603712] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33895.619776] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33895.619780] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33897.635858] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2042 tx timeout
[33897.635862] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[33897.642837] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[33914.248224] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-110)
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth.html.en

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: Check the packages that are upgradable. It could be related to grub-efi or shim: sudo apt list --upgradable If grub-efi or shim packages appear, upgrade them: sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed