# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS “No Bluetooth found Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth”

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, lts

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual boot the bluetooth doesn't work. When I use windows it works perfectly.

I have been struggling with ths problem for a long time and tried solutions from: [ubuntu 18.04 LTS bluetooth [0cf3:3004] discovery not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working)
["No Bluetooth found Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875901/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth)

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Some info about my system

Laptop Acer R13

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:57b8 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:2093 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


dmesg | grep -i blue 
[   51.881068] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   51.881082] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   51.881084] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   51.881085] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   51.881089] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   52.064798] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100100012d0d00
[   52.138403] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
[   52.233804] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   52.248810] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   65.718357] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   65.718359] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   65.718362] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown your system. It should work after boot.