# How to run a .sh file on startup

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. In my laptop, Bluetooth is not enabled by default.
It shows that `NO Bluetooth found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth`. I installed Bluez bluetooth and it activates my Bluetooth but I have to run some commands in order for it to activate every time I turn on my laptop.

Commands I have to run are,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
systemctl start bluetooth
sudo modprobe btusb 
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo service bluetooth restart
sudo modprobe rtbth
```

My questions,

1. How to run these commands automatically when the laptop turns on.
2. Sometimes even it is activated, it shows `Connection failed. Resources not ready`. and It won't connect no matter how much I wait.

I tried,
Putting these commands in a .sh file and including that inside rc.local and I used crontab too. Nothing seems to work.

Kindly help me in figuring it out.

Thanks.

Comment: For the Bluetooth issue, A [bios upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875901/no-bluetooth-found-plug-in-a-dongle-to-use-bluetooth/1359402#1359402) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Can you confirm that the script is NOT running? Execute `dmesg` and see if your script is in face called or not. Don't post it, just let us know if you found it in there.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see it running.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]